# How to make nginx serve multiple port redirects via ssl?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have one frontend and two backends running on my compute engine.

My first backend runs on port 5000 and the second backend on 5050. I am putting all my frontend files in a folder called `/var/www/html`.

And here is my nginx conf file:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name <server_name>;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
 
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name <server_name>;
    ssl_certificate <location_to_certificate>;
    ssl_certificate_key <location_to_private_key>;

    location / {
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

Now this works well to serve my frontend files with ssl but the backend apis which run on flask gunicorn with the following commands:

`gunicorn --workers 5 -b 0.0.0.0:5050 wsgi:app`

`gunicorn --workers 5 -b 0.0.0.0:5000 wsgi:app`

where these files are located into two different folders. I am not sure how to use nginx to listen to these two ports in https mode as well.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of lookup, I was able to achieve this by simply adding another listener server as shown below:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name <server_name>;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
 
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name <server_name>;
    ssl_certificate <location_to_certificate>;
    ssl_certificate_key <location_to_private_key>;

    location / {
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
    }
}

server {
    listen 5050 ssl;
    server_name <server_name>;
    ssl_certificate <location_to_certificate>;
    ssl_certificate_key <location_to_private_key>;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:<location_to_,sockfile>;
    }
}
```

Additionally, to create `.sock` file, I referred to this tutorial: `https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04`

Once the `.sock` file is created the process becomes very straight forward. If you get a `502 bad gateway` error that means you have configured your nginx.conf file correctly but you need to connect nginx and gunicorn and to debug such issues I found this [guide](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/nginx-502-bad-gateway-errors-gunicorn/) really helpful.

The best takeaway was that you can always assess your logs in `/var/log/nginx/` and look for `errors.log` and `access.log` to debug the issues even faster.